# Can you find shortest path using BFS?

Tags: graph, breadth-first-search, shortest-path, dijkstra

If I have a weighted graph and I run BFS but for each node I keep a track of the distance of origin, so I will keep visiting it whenever a node has an edge to it and it can reduce its distance. This should work? What is the runtime?

Comment: Research suggestion for you: Dijkstra algorithm.